Echo Cancellation in IOS [Flutter]: Preventing Speaker Audio from Being Recorded
Problem
I'm developing a Flutter IOS application that simultaneously plays and records audio. The problem is the sound from the speaker is being picked up by the microphone. I need to implement echo cancellation or something to prevent this.
Current Implementation
I'm using the following packages:

flutter_sound for audio playback and recording
audio_session for audio session management

Key Components:

Audio Playback: Using FlutterSoundPlayer for streaming PCM audio
Recording: Using FlutterSoundRecorder with PCM16 codec
Audio Session: Configured for simultaneous playback and recording

What I've Tried
Using AVAudioSessionMode.voiceChat but this plays the audio through the phones earpiece instead of main speaker
Relevant Code Snippets
import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';

class AudioSessionManager {
  static final AudioSessionManager _instance = AudioSessionManager._internal();
  factory AudioSessionManager() => _instance;

  AudioSessionManager._internal();
  late AudioSession _audioSession;
  bool _isInitialized = false;

  Future<void> init() async {
    if (_isInitialized) return;
    
    _audioSession = await AudioSession.instance;

    await _audioSession.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration(
      // iOS configuration
      avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.playAndRecord,
      avAudioSessionCategoryOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth |
          AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker |
          AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowAirPlay,
      avAudioSessionMode: AVAudioSessionMode.defaultMode,
      avAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy: AVAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy.defaultPolicy,
      avAudioSessionSetActiveOptions: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.none,
    ));

    _isInitialized = true;

    // Activate the audio session
    await _audioSession.setActive(true);
  }

  AudioSession get audioSession => _audioSession;
  bool get isInitialized => _isInitialized;
}

